# Is it possible to pass arguments to Siri-launched app?

Tags: ios

Siri can launch an app, but I tried "Launch Foo with arguments test" and "Launch Foo with args test" and didn't get any values in `main`. This discourages me, but can anyone provide a definitive answer as to whether one can retrieve "the command line" from Siri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible in any way.